# Problem with a simple script

Tags: scripting, aix

I have a problem with a script in AIX, but I can't find the mistake.  I want to copy files between two directories but checking first the existence of those directories. What I'm doing is this:

```
PATH=/home/fede/
PATH2=/home/prueba/
if [ -d $PATH ];
then
find $PATH -type f -exec cp {} $PATH2 \;
        echo "se copiaron los archivos correctamente"
else
        echo "no existe"
fi
```

But I receive this message: `./scriptTB[5]: find:  not found. se copiaron los archivos correctamente`. The last line says "The files were copied correctly" in Spanish. The name of the script is `scriptTB`.

Do I have to put anything before `find`? It seems that the problem is in  `find`.

Comment: do you mind editing your post to format the code correctly? Simply highlight it, then press the '{}' button in the text box. Thanks

Comment: `$PATH` is a default environment variable which tells your system where to find its program binaries (like the `find` program you are trying to use), so you should use a different name for that variable. I am betting that you are overwriting your system's `$PATH`, and now your system cannot find the `find` program. Try this and see if it works.

Comment: also if you want to test this and see what I mean, simply open a new terminal and run `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Hey thanks. That was the problema. Thank you !!

Do I have to "close" this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$PATH` is a default environment variable which tells your system where to find its program binaries (like the `find` program you are trying to use), so you should use a different name for that variable. I am betting that you are overwriting your system's `$PATH`, and now your system cannot find the `find` program. Try this and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

`PATH` happens to be the environment variable used by the shell to locate executables.  If you unset it or change it, the shell might not find commands such as `find` or `cp`.

It would be better if you used lowercase variable names in scripts. It is less likely that they collide with important environment variables.

In this case, you could use `source_dir` and `target_dir`, for example, which have the additional benefit of providing the reader with a bit of documentation.